# Convert string to smalldatetime before a database insert

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have everything inserting fine until I try to insert a string "09/21/3013" into the ArrivalDate column which is a smalldatetime. How do I convert this so I can insert into the database? Thanks in advance!

Here's the code:

```
    private void ExecuteInsert(string BookingName, string BookedBy)
{
    string connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CateringAuthorizationEntities"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    string sql = "INSERT INTO tbBooking (BookingName, BookedBy, ArrivalDate) VALUES "
                + " (@BookingName, @BookedBy, @ArrivalDate)";

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[3];
        //param[0] = new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int, 20);
        param[0] = new SqlParameter("@BookingName", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        param[1] = new SqlParameter("@BookedBy", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        param[2] = new SqlParameter("@ArrivalDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.SmallDateTime);

        param[0].Value = BookingName;
        param[1].Value = BookedBy;
        param[2].Value = ArrivalDate;

        for (int i = 0; i < param.Length; i++)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param[i]);
        }

        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
    {
        string msg = "Insert Error:";
        msg += ex.Message;
        throw new Exception(msg);
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}

protected void BtnCatering_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {

        //call the method to execute insert to the database
        ExecuteInsert(BookingName.Text, BookedBy.Text);
        Response.Write("Record was successfully added!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `DateTime` instead of string.

Comment: which is best done with DateTime.ParseExact or DateTime.TryParseExact, depending on whether you want the result of a parsing failure to be an exception or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if (ArrivalDate != DBNull.Value)
                param[2].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(ArrivalDate);
            else
            {
                param[2].Value = // default value
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use DateTime instead of String.

```
param[2].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(ArrivalDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `DateTime.ParseExact` will allow you to control the exact conversion of your date:

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
param[2].Value = DateTime.ParseExact(ArrivalDate, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", provider);
```